# Parse simple JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

This is a very simple JSON string `{"a": "\"A"}` validated by [JSON lint](https://jsonlint.com/).

But when I do

```
var b = '{"a": "\"A"}';
JSON.parse(b);
```

I'm getting an error with the escaped `"` : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 8`. How to handle the case ? How to make this example work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is a special character in JSON, but it is also a special character in JavaScript string literals.

When the JavaScript processor parses the string to populate the variable `b`, the `\` is consumed.

This gives you the JSON:

```
{"a": ""A"}
```

You can see this if you just examine the string:

```js
var b = '{"a": "\"A"}';
alert(b);
```

… which is invalid.

You need to escape the `\` with another `\` so that you insert a `\` character into the data.

```
var b = '{"a": "\\"A"}';
```

```js
var b = '{"a": "\\"A"}';
alert(b);
```

Comment: I can't accept your answer yet (must wait 9 other minutes). But for my use case then : I have a string over which I don't have control but arrives like this (a JSON string which contains an escaped double quote). How do I reformat it so that it becomes a valid JSON ?

Comment: Badly. It's broken data. Fixing it from the wrong end is always going to be a matter of guesswork.